# Unable to delete User objects in Django

Tags: python, django, exception

I have a try except block in one of my Django view functions that will delete a User object that was created in the try block if anything should fail. When I attempt to delete the User I get this error message.

```
OperationalError: no such table: reversion_revision
```

The same issue happens in the Django admin as well. I am having issues finding similar cases of this OperationalError happening to other people, and am not sure why it is happening. All the other objects that I am deleting in the except block delete without any issues.

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    # """Register a new account with a new org."""
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = SignUp(requestPost(request))

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

            email = cleaned_data['email']
            password = cleaned_data['password']
            org_name = cleaned_data['org_name']
            org_username = cleaned_data['org_username']

            if cleaned_data['token']:
                invite_token = cleaned_data['token']
            else:
                invite_token = cleaned_data['invite']

            try:
                account = Account.objects.create(email=email, password=password)
                x = email[:30]
                userExists = User.objects.filter(username=email[:30])
                if not userExists:
                    if len(email) < 30:
                        user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)
                    else:
                        email = email[:30]
                        user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)

                if invite_token:
                    if ThreadInvite.objects.filter(token=invite_token):
                        invitation = ThreadInvite.objects.get(token=invite_token)
                        thread = Thread.objects.get(id=invitation.thread.id)
                        ThreadMember.objects.create(thread=thread, account=account)
                    else:
                        invitation = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=invite_token)
                        if invitation.used:
                            raise Exception("invitation code is invalid")
                        org = Org.objects.get(id=invitation.org.id)
                        OrgMember.objects.create(org=org, account=account)
                        invitation.used = False
                        invitation.save()
                        add_to_welcome(org_id=org.id, account_id=account.id)

                if org_username and org_name:
                    org = Org.objects.create(name=org_name, username=org_username,
                                             actor=account)
                    OrgMember.objects.create(account=account, org=org)
                    Thread.objects.create(name='welcome', account=account, owner=account, org=org,
                                          purpose='To welcome new members to the team.')
                    add_to_welcome(org_id=org.id, account_id=account.id)

                login(request)

                md = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY)
                t = invite_token.replace(' ', '+')
                url = "https://localhost:8000/verify/{}".format(t)
                message = {
                    'global_merge_vars': [
                        {
                            'name': 'VERIFICATION_URL',
                            'content': url
                        },
                    ],
                    'to': [
                        {
                            'email': 'tim@millcreeksoftware.biz',
                        },
                    ],
                    'subject': 'Welcome to Human Link',
                }
                message['from_name'] = message.get('from_name', 'Humanlink')
                message['from_email'] = message.get('from_email',
                                                    'support@humanlink.co')
                try:
                    md.messages.send_template(
                        template_name='humanlink-welcome', message=message,
                        template_content=[], async=True)
                except mandrill.Error as e:
                    logging.exception(e)
                    raise Exception(e)

                context = {
                    'message': 'ok'
                }

                return composeJsonResponse(200, "", context)

            except Exception, e:
                logging.error(e)
                Account.objects.filter(email=email, password=password).delete()
                User.objects.filter(username=email[:30]).delete()
                Org.objects.filter(name=org_name, username=org_username).delete()
```

Structure

```
├── account
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── api_helpers.py
├── api_helpers.pyc
├── app
│   └── components
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── angular
│   ├── angular-animate
│   ├── angular-bootstrap
│   ├── angular-cookies
│   ├── angular-messages
│   ├── angular-sanitize
│   ├── angular-scroll-glue
│   ├── angular-touch
│   ├── angular-ui-router
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── checklist-model
│   ├── font-awesome
│   ├── jquery
│   ├── moment
│   ├── pusher-websocket-iso
│   └── underscore
├── cron_tasks.py
├── gulpfile.js
├── logs
│   └── readme.txt
├── manage.py
├── message
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
|
├── org
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── package.json
├── readme.txt
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── base.pyc
│   ├── cron.py
│   ├── development.py
│   ├── development.pyc
│   └── production.py
├── sqlite3
│   └── local.db
├── stylesheets
│   └── less
├── templates
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── admin
│   ├── dashboard
│   ├── footer.html
│   ├── home
│   ├── layouts
│   ├── nav.html
│   ├── pages
│   ├── settings
│   ├── shared
│   ├── site-alert.html
│   └── site.html
├── third_party
│   ├── classytags
│   ├── dateutil
│   ├── django_pusher
│   ├── itsdangerous.py
│   ├── itsdangerous.pyc
│   ├── mandrill.py
│   ├── mandrill.pyc
│   ├── mptt
│   ├── pusher
│   ├── requests
│   ├── reversion
│   ├── six.py
│   ├── six.pyc
│   ├── suit
│   └── werkzeug
├── utility.pyc
├── webapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── webapp_admin
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    └── static
```

Comment: Beyond the actual question you are asking, might I suggest you use [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/)  to warp your function? It's meant to handle exactly the situation you have, rolling back changes when an error has occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is not in your code but in your database state. Looks like you added `django reversion` app. Which adds new Models in your project. Run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

or if you in 1.8+

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**Update**

If this doesn't help than there are no migrations for your 3rd-party app you need to first create them with

```
python manage.py makemigrations name_3rd_party_app
```

**Be careful with creating migrations on 3rd-party apps. When you run `makemigrations` it creates migrations in 3rd-party app  package. So it won't be in your code. And after you deploy it, or other user uses it there are will not be this migrations. So you need to supply custom path for created migrations with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#migration-modules**

And then run `migrate`

Comment: Hmmm I ran migrate and it says everything is up to date  " No migrations to apply. "

Comment: does `python manage.py makemigrations reversion` creates anything? What version of django and django-reversion you are using?

Comment: making migrations for the reversion app, and than doing a migrate worked. Im not sure why it wouldn't of done that for doing 'python manage.py makemigrations' without specifying an app so it would make application wide migrations, but it worked. Thanks !!

Comment: @TimothyJosephBaney read update. There may be some problems about which youn need to know.

Comment: Hmmm so in my settings file in the MIGRATON_MODULES dictionary would I put {'reversion': 'reversion.db_migrations'} ?

Comment: Can you add your project structure in your question?

Comment: Yep, just added the project structure. My main settings file is settings/base.py

Comment: Then I would do MIGRATON_MODULES = {'reversion': 'webapp.migrations.reversion'}. But you can set any other path that seems logical to store 3rd party migrations to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`./manage.py makemigrations revisions`

then

`./manage.py migrate`

or just delete the db file and start over with

`./manage.py migrate`