# Migrate models outside current app

Tags: django, migration

I'm using django-modeltranslation in a Django 1.8 project. This app generates fields on the fly to store translations. It's possible to mark models as translatable by creating an Options class, like registering models with the Django admin.

I marked a model from a third party app as translatable. Django's migrations system picks up the changes and generates migrations in the app outside of my project. I want to store these migrations in an app in my project, how can I do that? I can only give a model name to migration operations, not a fully qualified app name.model name string.

Comment: I recently answered almost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623629/unable-to-delete-user-objects-in-django/37623715#37623715 read Update part

Comment: Yes, using settings.MIGRATION_MODULES kind of solved this problem. However, this third party app has migrations of it's own. I copied that migration set and added my own migrations to it. The only problem is that I have to manually copy any new migrations if there is a new version.

Comment: New migrations from third party app will occupy same migration indexes as you did in your custom migrations. So you will probably have to do more than just copying if new migrations will be added to this third party project. You can just freeze version of this app in you [requirements.txt](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files). So there won't be any unplanned model changes for this app.